# HP-620 не подключается к wi-fi

Tags: wifi, wireless

Не подключается к интернету через wi-fi, во время соединения возвращает ошибку "соединение потеряно, больше не присоединено с 802-11-wireless **название сети**".

02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci

Comment: произвольная строка описания — это фигня. вы циферки приведите, идентифицирующие устройство.

Comment: Какие именно циферки привести?

Comment: в самом начале строки в выводе программы `lspci`. выкладывайте всю строку, не ошибётесь: `$ lspci | grep -i ralink`

Comment: Т.е. я вижу wi-fi точки, могу начать подключение, но спустя некоторое время выбивает уведомление connection lost.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Извиняюсь за тупняк, у меня только wi-fi модуль не работает, etherner нормально справляется)